# Laravel 4 creating form open with database

Tags: php, jquery, css, forms, laravel

I have problem with my creating offers form.
Page displays nicely, but when you add data and after sending form, page gives error.
Laravel 4
[enter link description here](http://content.screencast.com/users/grupaoem/folders/Jing/media/07ff70fc-5e2d-43d5-b9e8-c73aeb3ccbce/2014-11-29_0339.png)
My routes:

```
Route::get('/user/{username}', array(
'as' => 'profile-user',
'uses' => 'ProfileController@user'
));


 Route::get('/profile/offers', array(
    'as' => 'profile-offers',
    'uses' => 'OffersController@offers'
    ));


Route::post('/profile/offers', array( 
    'as' => 'profile-offers', 
    'uses' => 'OffersController@postDestroy' ));


Route::post('/profile/offers/create', array(
           'as' => 'profile-create',
           'uses' => 'OffersController@postCreate'
    ));
```

My controller 
controllers/OffersController.php

```
    <?php


class OffersController extends BaseController {

public function __construct() {

    $this->beforeFilter('csrf', array('on'=>'post'));
            $this->beforeFilter('user');

}

public function Offers() {
    $offers = array();

    foreach(Category::all() as $category) { 
        $categories[$category->id] = $category->name;
    }

    //return View::make('offers.index')
    return View::make('profile.offers')
        ->with('offers', Offer::all())
        ->with('categories', $categories);
}

public function postCreate() {
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), Offer::$rules);

    if($validator->passes()){
        $offer = new Offer;
        $offer->category_id = Input::get('category_id');
        $offer->title = Input::get('title');
        $offer->description = Input::get('description');
        $offer->price = Input::get('price');

        $image = Input::file('image');
        $filename = date('Y-m-d-H:i:s').'.'.$image->getClientOriginalName();
        $path = public_path('img/offers/' . $filename);
        Image::make($image->hetRealPath())->resize(468, 249)->save('public/img/offers/'.$filename);
        $offer->image = 'img/offers/'.$filename;

        $offer->save();
        //return Redirect::route('profile-user', Auth::user()->username);
        return Redirect::to('profile.offers.create') //
            ->with('global', 'Dodano ogloszenie');
    }
    //return Redirect::route('profile-user', Auth::user()->username);
    return Redirect::to('profile.offers')
        ->with('global', 'Cos poszlo nie tak')
        ->withErrors($validator)
        ->withInput();
}

public function postDestroy(){
    $offer = Offer::find(Input::get('id'));

    if ($offer){
        File::delete('public/'.$offer->image);
        $offer->delete();
        //return Redirect::route('profile-user', Auth::user()->username);
        return Redirect::to('profile.offers.destroy')
            ->with('global', 'Skasowano ogłoszenie');

    }
}

public function postToggleAvailability() {
    $offer = Offer::find(Input::get('id'));

    if ($offer){
        $offer->availability = Input::get('availability');
        $offer->save();
        //return Redirect::route('profile-user', Auth::user()->username);

        return Redirect::to('profile.offers')->with('global', 'Zaktualizowano')
        ->with('global', 'Zaktualizowano');
    }
    //return Redirect::route('profile-user', Auth::user()->username);

    return Redirect::to('profile.offers')->with('global', 'zle ogloszenie')
    ->with('global', 'Zaktualizowano');
}


}
```

my views
views/profile/offers

```
        <h1>Offerts</h1>

    <ul>
        @foreach($offers as $offer)
            <li>
                {{ HTML::image($offer->image, $offer->title, array('width'=>'50')) }}
                {{ $offer->title }} -
                {{ Form::open(array('url'=>'profile/offers/destroy', 'class'=>'form-inline')) }}
                {{ Form::hidden('id', $offer->id) }}
                {{ Form::submit('delete') }}
                {{ Form::close() }} -

                {{ Form::open(array('url'=>'profile/offers/toggle-availability', 'class'=>'form-inline')) }}
                {{ Form::hidden('id', $offer->id) }}
                {{ Form::select('availability', array('1'=>'In Stock', 'O'=>'Out of Stock'), $offer->availability)}}
                {{ Form::submit('Update') }}
                {{ Form::close() }}


            </li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>

    <h2>Create new offers</h2><hr>

    @if($errors->has())
    <div id="form-errors">
        <p>the following errors have occurred:</p>

        <ul>
            @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
    @endif


    {{ Form::open(array('url'=>'profile/offers', 'method' => 'POST', 'files'=>true)) }}
    <p>
        {{ Form::label('category_id', 'Category') }}
        {{ Form::select('category_id', $categories) }}

    </p>

    <p>
      {{ Form::label('title') }}
     {{ Form:: text('title', null, array('class' => 'form-control', 'required' => '')) }}
    </p>
    <p>
        {{ Form::label('description') }}
        {{ Form:: text('description', null, array('class' => 'form-control', 'required' => '')) }}
    </p>
    <p>
        {{ Form::label('price') }}
        {{ Form::text('price', null, array('class'=>'form-price')) }}

    </p>

    <p>
        {{ Form::label('image', 'Choose an image') }}
        {{ Form::file('image') }}
    </p>



    {{ Form::submit('Create offers', array('class'=>'secondary-cart-btn')) }}
    {{ Form::close() }}
```

My models/Offer.php

```
<?php
class Offer extends Eloquent {

    protected $fillable = array('category_id,', 'title', 'description', 'price', 'availability',   'image');

    public static $rules = array(
            'category_id'=>'required|integer',
            'title'=>'required|min:2',
            'description'=>'required|min:20',
            'price'=>'required|numeric',
            'availability'=>'integer',
            'image'=>'required|image|mimes:jpge,jpg,bmp,png,gif'
        );

    public function category() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Category');
    }

}
```

Comment: Database record is not added automatically after completing the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have the route for the POST request and have not correctly set-up the routes for the rest of your controller actions, hence the 404 exception. Form submissions have method of `POST` unless explicitly specified to GET. You also have to properly set the controller action you want. Laravel will not know `profile/offers/destroy` should route to `postDestroy()` unless you tell it to.

```
Route::post('/profile/offers/destroy', array(
       'as' => 'profile-destroy',
       'uses' => 'OffersController@postDestroy'
));
```

You have to do this each for your controller action.

Comment: i thing that problem is in

      {{ Form::submit('Create offers', array('class'=>'secondary-cart-btn')) }}
i added

     Route::get('/profile/offers', array(
     'as' => 'profile-offers',
     'uses' => 'OffersController@offers'
      ));

     Route::get('/profile/offers/destroy', array(
       'as' => 'profile-destroy',
       'uses' => 'OffersController@postDestroy'
     ));


     Route::get('/profile/offers/create', array(
       'as' => 'profile-create',
       'uses' => 'OffersController@postCreate'
     ));
it does not change anything

Comment: Change `Route::get('/profile/offers/destroy', array( 'as' => 'profile-destroy', 'uses' => 'OffersController@postDestroy' ));`  to `Route::post('/profile/offers/destroy', array( 'as' => 'profile-destroy', 'uses' => 'OffersController@postDestroy' ));` . I edited my answer. Your form route should be POST so the one for create should also be POST

Comment: Roughly removal work, but I have a problem with adding listings to the database. postCreate does not work

Comment: Your creation form is routing to postDestroy(). Change the url in the blade view:
`{{ Form::open(array('url'=>'profile/offers/create', 'method' => 'POST', 'files'=>true)) }}`

Comment: Thank you, everything works;)
Just one problem. When I added it adds png image it is ok, but as adds jpg image it returns a message that there is something wrong ...

Comment: I think you misspelled `jpeg` in your Offers model image allowed mime rule.